running new feeder from exposed-basement load center to basement wall-mounted subpanel, + adj. duplex receptacle, THEN outside for 2 deck circuits
Project Context: about to place deck boards on wholly redone, raised, attached, front of house/front door accessing, 6'x20' deck. We are in IL, just south of the WI state line.
Before laying these boards, I'd like to run the electrical for receptacles. Under deck access will be available moving forward, but cramped and sloped. I'd like to also run wiring for LV landscape lighting, but that will have to wait. My wife just wants the deck done, and since I'm the one who does all of the outside maintenance, holiday decorating, etc, am the only one who sees the value of forethought vs just getting it done.
What I'd like to do is:

run 20A feeder 70' total (two 90deg turns) from the house's main 200A service panel (oppo corner of the  rectangular basement) to just about where the outside electrical will exit the basement. Mount subpanel here.

have outside, two separate branch circuits: under deck receptacles (6 or 8 duplex boxes) affixed toward the deck's rim joists (these will support numerous holiday decorations and possibly extension cords for occasional powered tool works) AND receptacles that will be up and available toward the house-side of the deck, for access and use by people sitting on the deck.

I'd like both outdoor circuits switch controlled, for which I'd have a dual switch box mounted in the deck corner. This would allow, for example, someone to "turn off" either/both circuits as desired. Some times it's nice to sit outside and have no more than star or moon light.


Regarding the dual receptacle mounted adjacent to the indoor subpanel, that would be for plug-in of a landscape lighting transformer.
I've been researching these, and feel like I'd prefer to have that transformer mounted indoors, next to the subpanel, with the only exiting considerations being the LV wiring and the thin lead for lighting photocell, which would get mounted nearby.
Reasoning is our layout doesn't make easy "hiding" the LV transformer outside, weather impacts are negated, LV controller access is as easy as walking down into the basement.
Ideally, this LV circuit too would have an outside mounted switch box, into which probably three separate lighting zones could be independently switched on/off, downstream of the photocell.
While the LV lighting is a separate project altogether, I bring it up simply because of my interest in powering that transformer off the same feeder circuit as supplies the deck outlets.
I understand the wet environment considerations, so that's being factored into my materials list, incl in-use, weather-resistant covers, weatherproof switch box, etc. NEMA 3R or even 4 for an outside junction box, should that be needed/recommended.
I aim to use 12/3 solid for the outdoor circuits, probably out of a Southwire 12/3 Black/White/Green Solid CU CoilPAK SIMpull THHN Tri-Wire.
I'd likely use Schedule 80 for all outdoor straight runs, with each receptacle box fed wiring via LiquidTight. All receptacles will be pigtailed, instead of series wired. I figured I'd have each outdoor circuit's first receptacle be a GFCI, providing that required coverage to each downstream receptacle.
I can draw something out and post it, if that's preferred.
I've been reading, researching and thinking about this for long enough now that I've some sort of paralysis by analysis going on, and as mentioned, a wife who has and is being pretty patient, but now that Spring has sprung, that's about to come to a swift end. She just wants back her deck. I get it; I do too.
Appreciate in advance any/every ones' time, attention and assistance.
EDIT: Point was made that the Southwire CoilPAK via H.D. shows as THHN, when THWN is required. Here's a C/P directly from Southwire's site, covering CoilPAK:
Southwire® SIMpull THHN® copper conductors as part of the SIMpull CoilPAK™ Wire Payoff are primarily used in conduit and cable trays for branch circuits in commercial or industrial applications as specified in the National Electrical Code. Voltage for all applications is 600 volts. SIMpull THHN® copper conductors are designed to be installed without application of a pulling lubricant. These conductors have multiple ratings. Depending upon the product application, allowable temperatures are as follows:
THHN or T90 Nylon- Dry locations not to exceed 90° C
THWN-2- Wet or dry locations not to exceed 90° C or locations not to exceed 75° C when exposed to oil
TWN75- Wet locations not to exceed 75° C
MTW- Wet locations or when exposed to oil at temperatures not to exceed 60° C or dry locations not to exceed 90° C (with ampacity limited to that for 75° C conductor temperature per NFPA 79)
AWM- Dry locations not to exceed 105° C only when rated and used as appliance wiring material


what are you waiting for

Caution: one of the images for CoilPaks from the HD webpage states "now available in both THHN and THWN-2 variants". Seems odd since I haven't seen any THHN that wasn't dual rated as THWN in years, but you absolutely need THWN for Wet locations.

Traveler: hahaha...sounds like you've talked with my wife

NoSparksPlease: yes, understood re: THWN required. Seems there are multiple wire makers with dual rated THHN/THWN, despite being unclear in marking. I did go to the Southwire site and updated my OP with a direct C/P from the site for their CoilPak. Also found following under the product page's construction tab: Marked as THHN and THWN-2 in all sizes.

Put the GFCIs inside, too. Even "weather resistant" ones die faster outside.
If your LV needs are small enough, plug the transformer into one of those. If you need Moah Powah! just put two deadfront GFCIs inside for the two circuits going outside, before they go outside, and run the LVT off its own circuit breaker on the sub-panel.
Remember to allow for working space at the sub-panel. 30" wide, 36" out, 78" high, kept clear at all times (not useable for storage.) Sometimes that means running 2 or 3 circuits from the main (or a subpanel by the main, sharing or only slightly increasing its working space) is the better option.
Using solid wire in conduit is like slapping yourself in the face. Stranded is more flexible and easier to pull and generally costs maybe a penny more per foot at these sizes. Get quality outlets with screw-and-clamp attachments for the wires that don't make connecting stranded wires irritating, and use stranded wire.
If you do the conduit right, you don't have to get the wiring done to get the deck on and the wife happy. Just get the outside conduit done and the deck over it, then worry about the electrical after the deck is on.

Besides, if he does the conduit first then does the electrical later, that certainly satisfies the code requirement that all conduit needs to be assembled first before putting wires in it.

Milwrdfan: I'd planned on "doing" conduit/boxes/receptacles/wiring all on the same day. Not trying to crawl around under the finished deck to run electrical, or crawl around under the deck for anything, really. Ease of access, to these old-ish bones, is pretty high up the priority list, if I have anything to say about it.

Ecnerwal: FWIW, 350' CoilPAK solid is (pre-tax) $178; 350' CoilPAK stranded $263.63. I was under impression that solid is the way to go when wiring isn't going to be moved/moving, and that solid has higher load capacity/lower voltage drop/lower impedence due to less surface area than stranded. Out of the basement and under a pretty small deck didn't strike me as too bad. Were I running whole house electrical...yeah, I hear ya.

Manufacturer states: The wire is covered with a tough heat and moisture resistant PVC insulation with an overall nylon jacket utilizing SIMpull® Technology. The claim is made that pulling requires no lubrication application. Haven't used it, so for all I know there's an application of snake oil. Figured that 3/4" Schedule 80 would have plenty of room for (3) 12AWG pulls.

@Ecnerwal: Just so I'm clear, code allows me to put each branch circuit's GFCI inside, and then route wiring outside to each circuit's respective receptacles? As far as plugging the LVT into one of those, oh yeah, that most certainly could work! I see no real-life situation in which it's dark enough outside for landscape lighting to switch on by photocell, and still have power tools in operation. Slim and none, really. What of the outdoor switches controlling each circuit? How would those fit into the layout with the leading GFCIs inside?

Absolutely the GFCIs can go inside. If you want to pay too much they can be the breakers - I prefer normal breaker and GFCI next for less expense when, not if, they fail (I've been around long enough to consider things that last for 10-15 years "temporary, will need to be replaced.") You might want to shop individual spools of wire at an electrical supply. HD can be very overpriced, and "convenience-pack" stuff always is. Switches go after the GFCIs since they are outside. It's not a problem unleess the switch has a ground fault, and then you replace the switch as defective.

Likewise, if you use individual spools, you're not pulling 2 or 3 ground wires where you only need one per conduit.
